# Using npm on a Rails app, deployed to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, npm

I have some front end assets that uses some node packages to compile (typescript/minifier/handlebars). I'd like the compilation of my front end assets to be part of a post deploy process, so that I don't need to check in those files and it's always fresh.

Currently I'm stuck at the point of getting npm on a heroku instance. All the resources I've found point to setting up a node.js app (which doesn't help me).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by adding a nodejs buildpack:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
```

It's important to have the nodejs buildpack added first, otherwise the npm build still fails.

More on buildpacks: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app